# logResponse Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, program-entry-point

I have searched and found a few responses that didn't seem to help and I am stuck with an nullPointerException error. Below is my code the error is in my logResponse() method, any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Survey21 {

    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String surveyTitle;
    private static int rID;
    private static int respondentID;
    private int[][] responses;

    //Constructors
    // Default Constructor
    Survey21() {
        surveyTitle = "Customer Survey";
    }

    // Overloaded Constructor 1
    Survey21(String title, int rID) {
        surveyTitle = title;
        rID = 0;
        generateRespondentId();
    }

    Survey21(int[][] surveyArray) {
        responses = surveyArray; // store responses
    }

    public static int getrID() {
        return rID;
    }

    public static void setRespondentID(int respondentID) {
        respondentID = rID;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return surveyTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        surveyTitle = title;
    }

    public static int generateRespondentId() {
        rID = ++respondentID;
        return rID;
    }

    // displays name of survey and entire grid of results
    public void displaySurveyResults() {
        System.out.printf("%s\n\n", getTitle());
        logResponse();


    }

    // dispalys question number and results for that question so far
    public void displayQuestionStats(int questionNumber) {
    }

    // enter questions and store in an array of Strings
    public void enterQuestions() {
        /*String[] questions = {
         "How would you rate your online shopping experience?",
         "How satisfied was you with the purchase price?",
         "Overall how was the online checkout experience?",
         "How likely are you to recommend your friends and family to our store?",
         "How concerned are you with online credit card security?",
         "How likely are you to prefer a retail location compared to an online store?",
         };*/
        String questions[] = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a question!");
            questions[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        /*TEST TEST***
         System.out.print(questions[0] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[1] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[2] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[3] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[4] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[5] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[6] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[7] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[8] + "\n");
         System.out.print(questions[9] + "\n");
         */

    }

    **// enters the response in the correct grid 
    public void logResponse() {
        System.out.println("The responses are:\n");
        System.out.print("            "); // align column heads
        // create a column heading for each question
        for (int qNumber = 0; qNumber < responses[0].length; qNumber++) {
            System.out.printf("Question number %d ", qNumber + 1);
            System.out.println("Response"); // column heading 
        }
        for (int response = 0; response < responses.length; response++) {
            System.out.printf("Response %2d", response + 1);
            for (int qNumber : responses[response])// output responses
            {
                System.out.printf("%8d", qNumber);
            }
        }
    }**
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want the length of your array and not the length of your first element:

```
for (int qNumber = 0; qNumber < responses.length; qNumber++) {
    System.out.printf("Question number %d ", qNumber + 1);
    System.out.println("Response"); // column heading 
}
```

Comment: Customer Survey

The responses are:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

             at Survey21.logResponse(Survey21.java:108)
 at Survey21.displaySurveyResults(Survey21.java:62)
 at SurveyTest21.main(SurveyTest21.java:16)
Java Result: 1

Comment: It looks like your responses array is null. You're not setting your response array in every constructor. Which constructor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't initialize my array properly I did

```
private int[][] responses;
```

and it should have been

```
private int[][] responses = new int[5][11];
```